# Is it possible to insert data to tables with unique id that appear in database in order without locking?

Tags: mysql

I need to insert some data to mysql table. This data will be fetched to other system using id. It's know last id and get all after it.

But if id 3 will appear after 4 in database this record would never be synchronized with other system.

Is it possible to insert data to tables with unique id that appear in database in order without locking?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Here i put a link for make you some example:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-the-next-auto-increment-id-in-mysql

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT cannot be used because of not finished transactions. You start transaction with id 3, then start transaction with id 4, then commit transaction with 4 and you base have 1,2,4, then commit transaction with 3 and you have 1,2,3,4 -- 3 appears after 4